# scheduling SQL jobs one after other

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two jobs at same time Let say a and b....
I need to run the jobs in a sequence

first =-----a

second=----b

both a and b scheduling times should be different so that I cant use them in single job
when I schedule them they are running parallel I required a sequence of execution.

Comment: Why don't you create 1 job which does actions of `-----a` and `----b`?

Comment: Instead of scheduling them as two separate jobs, create one job to perform actions one after the other

Comment: there should be two seperate jobs. but execute in sequence

Comment: why they tow separate jobs ??is there any problem is they are under a main job ? follow a master slave model , or use one sp to execute them,  EXEC dbo.sp_start_job N'job1' ;

Comment: try  EXEC dbo.sp_start_job N'firstjob' ;
GO
EXEC dbo.sp_start_job N'secondjob' ;

Comment: both are scheduled at different timeings but they will coinside one in hour. can we execute in order

Comment: @koushikveldanda the solution is a single job with 2 steps. if you can't do that please explain. why you can't apply the simplest solution? please understand that without that information you are preventing us to help you.

Comment: both a and b scheduling times should be different so that I cant use them in single job

Comment: please share both jobs schedule

Comment: one is for 15 min and other for 30 min

Answer (score 1):

- One job every 30 minutes to do Task A starting 00:15
- Other job every 30 minute do Tasks A and then B staring 00:00

Answer (score 0):

If the actual requirement is that two separate activities should not take place *at the same time*, but that they have completely different scheduling requirements, you may be able to achieve this using an application lock.

This would require that all activity for each job happens within a single stored procedure (or, in some other way, is forced to use a single database session).

At the start of each activity, the code would call [`sp_getapplock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx), something like:

```
EXEC sp_getapplock N'D1852F12-F213-4BD3-A87C-10FB56506EF8',
                   N'Exclusive',
                   N'Session'
```

(Ideally, the lock is released afterwards using [`sp_releaseapplock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178602.aspx))